# android radiobuttons ID changing

Tags: android, radio-button

I have 3 radiobuttons in my app and I am getting the ID of the selected one like this:

```
  int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```

And then in my if condition I compared it:

```
  if( selectedId == 2131230992  { do something...}
 else if( selectedId == 2131230993{ do something...}
else {...}
```

However this was working very well, but suddenly I noticed in my live app, that the radiobuttons doesn't work anymore.

I debugged it and found out, that when I log the value of radiobuttons ID, it is now different as before.

```
Log.e("ID", String.valueOf(selectedId));
```

Now it is 2131231081, 2131231081, 2131231083 etc.

How are these ID changing and why? During my app build these ID's were fixed numbers, so I used them in my conditions, but now there are totally different ID's.

So what should be the correct way to check which radiobutton is selected, if the ID's can't be used this way?

Comment: why you didn't set the id on your xml file instead of using this number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use directly Resource IDs because them could be change at any Build. You have to resolve their Names to their IDs at runtime using "*Context.getResources().getIdentifier(...)*" according to what kind of Resource you're looking for.

The right way is (pseudo-code):

```
@IdRes
int selected_id = RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()
if (selected_id == R.id.radiobutton1) {
    ...
}
```

where "*radiobutton1*" is a <RadioButton> inside its <RadioGroup> (in XML Layout file).

Comment: thanks for explaining, makes sense so that was the issue I didn't realize that the IDs were changing each build. Now it is clear for me.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this:

-> XML Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rg_test"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_one"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Radiobutton One" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_two"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Radiobutton Two" />
    </RadioGroup>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

-> Kotlin:

```
        // Getting the radio group from the layout
        val rg = findViewById<RadioGroup>(R.id.rg_test)

        // Initializing the radio button check change listener
        rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener { radioGroup, selectedId ->

            // Now, listening to the changed radio button here
            when (selectedId) {

                // Case 1
                R.id.rb_one -> {
                    // do something
                }

                // Case 2
                R.id.rb_two -> {
                    // do something
                }
            }
        }
```